# SQL query with Python doesn't work

Tags: python, sql

I wrote this code to delete duplicates from a table.
It works fine when executed in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 
but I can't get it to work executing with Python.

There is no error occuring, it's just not working ...
I tried executing other queries aswell without any problems.

Someone an idea what could be wrong ?
I'm using Python 2.7

```
import pymssql    
import time

conn = pymssql.connect(server='rfhete755', database='EEX')

c = conn.cursor()

p = """
    SELECT [ID]
        ,[Operator]
        ,[Source]
        ,[Timestamp]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY [Operator]
            ,[Source]
            ,[Timestamp] ORDER BY [Timestamp]
            ) AS Rnum
    FROM [EEX].[dbo].[Wind_Solar];

    WITH CTE
    AS (
        SELECT [Operator]
            ,[Source]
            ,[Timestamp]
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY [Operator]
                ,[Source]
                ,[Timestamp] ORDER BY [Timestamp]
                ) AS Rnum
        FROM [EEX].[dbo].[Wind_Solar]
        )
    DELETE
    FROM CTE
    WHERE Rnum <> 1"""

print p

c.execute(p)

time.sleep(2)

conn.commit()

time.sleep(1)

c.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Curious, why are you sleeping 2 seconds before committing?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: if you are going to arbitrarily reformat the SQL, at least don't break Python syntax.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It was't arbitrarily, but it's good to know that multi-line strings requires escaping the quotes, in Python. We can't all know every standard / syntax caveat.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: very few programming languages allow for newlines as literals in string definitions. C-like languages usually use the `\n` escape sequence to encode those, and using a literal newline is a syntax error.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Now that you mention it, I believe using a `\\` at the end of every line-break was also possible? Or was that just for the code and not variable values?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: depends on the language; It works in Python, but you are escaping the newline from the parser, so no newline is included in the string value.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Good to know, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cursor.execute()` can execute **one statement**. You are passing in multiple statements. Split out your operations into separate `cursor.execute()` calls:

```
select_all = """
    SELECT [ID]
        ,[Operator]
        ,[Source]
        ,[Timestamp]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY [Operator]
            ,[Source]
            ,[Timestamp] ORDER BY [Timestamp]
            ) AS Rnum
    FROM [EEX].[dbo].[Wind_Solar]"""
c.execute(select_all) 

delete_all_but_first = """
    WITH CTE
    AS (
        SELECT [Operator]
            ,[Source]
            ,[Timestamp]
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY [Operator]
                ,[Source]
                ,[Timestamp] ORDER BY [Timestamp]
                ) AS Rnum
        FROM [EEX].[dbo].[Wind_Solar]
        )
    DELETE
    FROM CTE
    WHERE Rnum <> 1"""
c.execute(delete_all_but_first)
```

Most likely you didn't mean to include the first `SELECT`.

I'm not sure why you are using `time.sleep()` statements in your Python code, those are not needed to ensure correct execution.

If you use the connection object and cursor as context manangers, they'll be automatically closed (unfortunately, the pymmsql project missed an opportunity to include transaction handling in their context manager implementation):

```
with pymssql.connect(server='rfhete755', database='EEX') as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as c:
       c.execute(delete_all_but_first)
    conn.commit()
```